# How can I render a partial in dynamicHepler?

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, partial, express

I'm using express in nodejs.

The following code seems to render my partial and respond it DIRECTLY to the client.

How can my dynamicHelper RETURN the rendered partial to the layout template instead of sending it to the client

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  menu: function(req, res) {
    // The following 
    return res.partial(
      __dirname + '/views/partials/menu', { locals: {
      nodes: asap.config.menus[key]
    }});
  } 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since express and connect new versions you can't as it would call `res.send()` twice.
I'm working on a commit to fix this issue. I hope to finish it soon and then we will see if TJ will merge it.